# Prove that the continuum hypothesis follows from the axiom of determinacy.

Tags: set-theory

**Prove** that the **continuum hypothesis** follows from the **axiom of determinacy**.

Denote by $B^{w}$ the set of all infinite sequences of $0$ and $1$. Let $A ⊂ B^{w}$
. Alternately, the $I$ and $II$ players make moves. I can name any finite sequence
of $0$ and $1$ in his turn (let's denote his moves $u0, u2$, . . .), and $II$ is the number $0$ or $1$ (let's denote his moves $u1, u3,$ . . .).
Thus they build an infinite sequence $u0u1u2$ . . . I the player will win, if $u0u1u2 . . . ∈ A$,
otherwise the $II$ player wins.

**The axiom of determinacy** states that in any such game, one of the players has a winning strategy.

**The continuum hypothesis** states that any subset of a continuum is either finite, or countable, or
continuous (in other words, there are no intermediate powers between a countable power and a continuum
).

*Hint*: what can we say about the power of $A$ if I has a winning strategy? And if $II$?

I want to prove that when player $II$ wins, our set $A$ contains a finite or countable number of elements. Why? In the first step, player $I$ chooses a word of finite length (let it be the word $w$) and then player $II$ has a winning strategy, let's assume that it is $1$, but if $I$ player wrote out the word $w0$ on $1$ turn, player $II$ still has a winning strategy, so for every word $w$ by $I$ player $II$ player wins both when choosing $w1$ and when choosing $w0$, but this is only an idea and I can't bring it to a strict proof

Comment: Maybe there is a direct proof, by you can also use the fact that under $\mathsf{AD}$ every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has perfect set property

Comment: @Lxm That's true, but it doesn't really help OP, since the proof of the perfect set property is essentially the same as the proof of CH that OP was asking about!

Answer (score 3):

We need to show that if Player II has a winning strategy, then $A$ is countable.

So suppose that Player II has a winning strategy $\sigma.$

For any $x\in A,$ there must be a maximal (partial) play $u_0\dots u_{2n-1}$ in the game such that:
(1) the play contains an even number of moves (that is, it ends with a move by Player II);
(2) Player II plays using the strategy $\sigma;$
and
(3) the play is compatible with $x$ — that is, the concatenation $u_0\,^\frown\dots^\frown\,u_{2n-1}$ is an initial subsequence of the infinite sequence $x.$
[If there were no maximal such play, we could use the strategy $\sigma$ repeatedly to construct a full (infinitely long) play that yields $x.$ But $x\in A$ and $\sigma$ is a winning strategy for Player II, guaranteeing that the resulting play is not in $A.]$

Now we want to see that if $u_0,\dots,u_{2n-1}$ is maximal for both $x$ and $y$ in $A,$ then $x=y.$ We'll prove by induction that $x\upharpoonright k = y\upharpoonright k$ for every natural number $k.$

Let $j$ be the length of the concatenation $u_0\,^\frown\dots^\frown\,u_{2n-1}.$  This concatenation is an initial subsequence of both $x$ and $y,$ so $x\upharpoonright j = u_0\,^\frown\dots^\frown\,u_{2n-1} = y\upharpoonright j.$ That's the basis of the induction.

For the induction step, if $k\ge j$ and $x\upharpoonright k = y\upharpoonright k,$ consider what happens in the game if, after $u_0, \dots, u_{2n-1},$ Player I plays the finite sequence $x\upharpoonright \{j,\dots,k-1\}$ (which equals $y\upharpoonright \{j,\dots,k-1\})$  as the next move, and Player II then plays the digit $v$ that the strategy $\sigma$ says to play, either $0$ or $1.$ By maximality of $u_0\,^\frown\dots^\frown\,u_{2n-1}$ for $x,$ we have $x(k) = 1-v.$ Similarly, by maximality for $y,$ we have $y(k) = 1-v.$  So $x(k)=y(k),$ and it follows that $x\upharpoonright (k+1) = y\upharpoonright (k+1).$

To complete the proof, let $S = \{ \mathbf u \mid \mathbf u \text{ is maximal for some }x\in A\},$ and let $f\colon S\to A$ be the function which takes any $\mathbf u\mathrm\,\in\,S$ to the unique $x\in A$ that $\mathbf u$ is minimal for. This function maps $S$ onto $A,$ and $S$ is a countable set (since $S$ is a subset of the set of finite sequences of $0$s and $1$s). It follows that $A$ is countable.

---

By the way, essentially the same proof as this proof of CH under AD actually shows the stronger statement that, under AD, any uncountable set of reals contains a perfect subset.